# how to remove english quote

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, text

I would like to know, how can I remove english quotes from a string?

e.g.: Denomina “CAMPOS” a Rua B, em local que especifica.

I want to remove this quotes, or replace it to simple quotes like "this quotes". I've tried this code, but it does not work:

```
Dim txt As String = mytext.Replace("““", """").Replace("””", """")
```

### Edits

Take a look an my code on Visual Studio 2010:

[image]

Comment: What you say your original code does not work, what does that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using asci instead of real quotes

Comment: Thanks dude, it works fine! Final code: dto.Ementa = item.Ementa.Replace(Chr(147), """").Replace(Chr(148), """")